# Google Analytics, AMP and Tag Manager, dynamic client calculated metric

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

I want Google Analytics to send a client calculated value on AMP.  I also use Google Tag Manager to embed analytics code on the page.

I want to send a value that is the difference between a time (unix) and current time on device.  There's a variable on Tag Manager named "{{Client Timestamp}}" and I define server side the other date.  But any time I send the value, get's turned to string (no matter if it's custom metric or custom dimension), for instance:
[image]
cm3: 1582720980844-1582641262000

Do you know any way I can achieve this?  Also tried with a generated hidden element with the value calculated, but I can't manage the set the correct value on this element without user interaction.

```
<amp-state id="my_data">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
            "my_date": SERVER_GENERATED_TIMESTAMP
        }
    </script>
</amp-state>
<span class="element_to_send_from_tag_manager" [text]="Date.now() - my_date">sample value</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a calculation inside a text field, that's why GTM is treating it as a string no matter what you do. If you want to run a calculation that is the difference of time between those two variables, use a [custom javascript variable](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7683362?hl=en) and push the result of that inside your secondary dimension.

Example of custom JS variable in GTM:

```
function() {
    var result = {{variable1}} - {{variable2}};
    return result;
}
```

EDIT:

Since we are talking about an AMP container, we cannot do the subtraction inside GTM itself, what we can use instead is the [Calculated Metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121409?hl=en) functionality inside GA itself.

Comment: The problem here is that GTM doesn't allow JS variables on AMP :(

Comment: You stand correct, my bad I forgot the lack of JS support in the container. What you could then do it split those two variables in two different dimensions and use the Calculated metrics functionality inside GA itself: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6121409?hl=en